# passing extra values into a partial and to a create action through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have a views/questions/show.html.erb page, which, in addition to the expected @question variable, also has access to an @answers variable to show all the answers to a particular question.

Inside of a loop that displays all of the answers to a particular question, I wish to display an area for a user to comment (on an answer not the question), so I created a comment partial in which, following the advice of another SO answer, I created a 'locals' hash to pass variables in.  In the create action of the Comments controller, I wish to have access to the answer (a comment belongs to an answer) and the question (which has_many :answers), so I passed in the answer and question id into the partial like so

```
   <% for answer in @answers %>
    ....(code ommitted)
    <%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => { :answer_id => answer.id, :question_id => @question.id } %>
    ...(code ommitted)

    <% end %>
```

and I pass the answer_id and the question_id through hidden fields in the comments partial like so

```
   <%= simple_form_for @comment do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content, as: :text, label: 'comment'%>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :answer_id, :value => answer_id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question_id %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
   <% end %>
```

In the create action of the comments controller, I do this

```
def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:comment][:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:comment][:answer_id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.build(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment"
        redirect_to root_path
        # redirect_to question_answers_path(@question) (will eventually want to redirect to the question)
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end 
end
```

First problem, I feel like I've done something awkward by having to extract the question id (and the answer id) in the following way

```
@question = Question.find(params[:comment][:question_id])
```

However, these are the params that are available as a result of submitting my form

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VtogfCsI137lbk2l64RXtrfRn/+Rt1/jM8pfDVY29gM=", "comment"=>{"content"=>"test", "user_id"=>"12", "answer_id"=>"25", "question_id"=>"22"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
```

so I have to dig out the question_id like this `params[:comment][:question_id]`

The second, more challenging problem (challenging for me) is that Rails is telling me

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: question_id
```

I have no reason to store the question_id on the comment model, so I didn't make a column for it in the database.  However, when I do this

```
@comment = @answer.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

since the question_id is one of the params inside :comment (which got there by me making the hidden field for it in the form), Rails is trying to save it in the comments table. However, the only reason I really want access to the question in the create action of the comments_controller.rb is to use it for redirecting back to the question after the save.

Can you suggest what I can do to fix this problem? I feel like since I don't have a lot of experience with Rails, I'm doing everything very awkwardly, which is probably the reason it's not working. I guess the easy way out of this problem is to add a question_id column to the comment model, but there's no 'association' between them, so I think it's the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is not a problem. 
There are not much ways to do that.

Second problem, you have to do like this

`@comment = @answer.comments.build(params[:comment][:content].merge(user_id: params[:comment][:user_id], answer_id: params[:comment][:answer_id]))`
because otherwise you'll try to assign attributes that you dont have in your table

or you can do another way

```
params[:comment].delete('question_id')
```

and then

```
@comment = @answer.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not only the :content I wish to save. I also need to save the user_id in the comments table. So how would i do that? like this? @comment = @answer.comments.build({params[:comment][:content], params[:comment][:user_id]})

Comment: Actually, it also needs to save the answer_id because comments belong_to :answer model.  Can you update your answer one more time? I basically need to save everything except the question_id

Comment: Actually, it gives me an error. The comment (which is a string) can't have merge called on it. Here's the error message:  undefined method `merge' for "this is a test comment":String

Comment: all you need is to build new @comment. then you can assign your values like `@comment.user_id = params[:comment][:user_id]` and then save it